# Noun + to + Verb - Grammar Structure

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

I saw this sentences below somewhere and am struggling with the grammar structure.

**" Britain to restrict promotion of unhealthy food from April 2022 "**

Just wonder why is " to " needed here in this sentence? if I were the writer, I would omit/cut "to" and make the verb restrict in plural form.

Can someone explain or give the title of this grammar structure? so I can chase down.

Comment: This appears to be culled from some newspaper and newspaper headlines are often written without strict adherence to grammatical details. It's perhaps an abridged version of _Britain is going to restrict....April 2022._

Comment: Britain plans to, Britain votes to. What are you thinking of “pluralizing”?

Comment: Thank you for both of your comments. What I am thinking in the first place is “Britain restricts” is the right one. However, I never knew that native english shorten the sentences like that which is a bit ambiguous to me since they could be “is going to / votes to / plans to” etc.